# Is repeating a loop twice the same as multiplication by $2$ in singular homology?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

I have the following problem understanding the notion of coefficients in Singular Homology. Let $X$ be a topological space (for example closed differential manifold). Let $x:[0,1]\rightarrow X$ be a continous path such that $x(0)=x(1)$. Then $x$ defines a homology class $[x]\in H_{1}(X;\mathbb{Z})$. Define a different path $\tilde{x}:[0,1]\rightarrow X$ by $\tilde{x}(t)=x(2t)$, for $t\in [0,1/2]$ and $\tilde{x}(t)=x(2t-1)$, for $t\in [1/2,1]$ (essentially the loop $x$ run twice).

**Question:** Do we have that $2[x]=[\tilde{x}]$ in $H_{1}(X;\mathbb{Z})$?

If yes  or no, then can you provide an explanation?

Greetings,
Milan

Comment: You are basically using the Hurewicz homomorphism.

Comment: Another formulation: as the map $t\mapsto 2t$ is the double covering $S^1\overset{\times 2}{\to} S^1$, the homology class $[\tilde{x}]$ is the image of the fundamental class of $S^1$ under the map $S^1\overset{\times 2}{\to} S^1\overset{x}{\to} X$. Thus it suffices to show that the double covering map doubles the fundamental clas of $S^1$, which you can find in most textbooks in algebraic topology, eg) Hatcher's.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Consider an oriented equilateral triangle $\Delta=e_0e_1e_2$, and let $f(P)=P’$ for every $P \in \Delta$, where $P’ \in [e_0,e_2]$ and the lines $PP’$ and $e_0e_2$ are perpendicular.

Then the boundary of $\tilde{x} \circ f$ is exactly $x+x-\tilde{x}$.